# moment locale not set correctly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

We're trying to find a problem with tests that use moment.js and fail when run on a server in Arizona but succeed when run locally here in the UK. We manually set the locale before creating a moment and can see that the local 'en-gb' is installed.

This fiddle highlights what I think the problem is (**Need to set computer to Arizona Time zone first!**) https://jsfiddle.net/2ve10ax4/

```
moment.locale('en-gb');
console.log(moment.locale());
// en-gb
console.log(moment('2016-05-01T00:00:00+00:00').format()); 
// 2016-04-30T17:00:00-07:00
```

I'm expecting to see the date formatted with respect to 'en-gb' locale but it shows it with respect to Arizona time. Am I missing something?

Comment: In this instance locale was the wrong concept.  What I needed is:
`moment.parseZone('2016-05-01T00:00:00+00:00')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading more I believe [parseZone](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) is the correct solution, given that I am already including Time Zone information in the date string.

`console.log(moment.parseZone('2016-05-01T00:00:00+00:00').format());`

Answer (score 1):

Locale and timezone are orthogonal things. A locale does not specify a timezone unambigously. You need to set your timezone separately. You can use Momemt Timezone, and then you can use e.g.

```
.tz('Europe/London')
```

Comment: But I have unambiguously specified the offset via the date format?

Comment: `moment('2016-05-01T00:00:00+00:00')` creates a new moment object, which stores a time instant. However, when you use `.format()`, it displays it in the timezone of the browser - which is correct in most cases.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes locale is not what I need!

Answer (score 1):

By setting `moment.locale('en-gb')` you have specified a locale/language (brittish-english), not a timezone.

To specify a timezone you need to include the [Moment.js Timezone library](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) in your project, and then do something like:

```
console.log(moment('2016-05-01T00:00:00+00:00').tz('America/Phoenix').format());
```

The above will give you the timezone for Arizona.