# Moment.js local ... another one

Tags: javascript, momentjs, local

I am trying to display a **`datestring` as local time**. I get the right offset, but local does not what it should:

```
function getDateString(dateString) {
    alert("Datestring: " + dateString);
    var dateObj = new Date(dateString);
    var momentTime = moment(dateObj);
    var offset = moment().utcOffset();
    alert("Offset " + offset);
    var withOffset = moment.utc(momentTime).utcOffset(offset);
    alert("with off " + withOffset);
    alert(withOffset.local().format('HH:mm'));
    return withOffset;
}
```

What I get from the alerts is:

```
Datestring: 2018-02-28T23:17:00
Offset 60
with off 1519856220000
23:17
```

The last one should be one hour later `: 00:17`.

What am I doing wrong? Why does `moment.js` know the offset but not adding it to `local()`? 
Global: `moment.locale('de');`
THX

Since noone seems to know an answer I made it easy:

```
  var offset = moment().utcOffset();
  return momentTime.add(offset, 'minutes');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment locale not set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703742/moment-locale-not-set-correctly)

Comment: I want to use the timezone of the browser. Thought with local moment.js should know the local timezone.

Comment: ParseZone not working, still 23:17.